# How can we store Shield UI treeview data locally using angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, treeview, shieldui

I am using Sheild UI - tree view widget to construct tree view. Here I am dragging data from different div and drop into this ui-treeview div. I want to bind data to this tree view dynamically. Also, I need to store this component and its data in local storage using angular js. Looking forward for your assistance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the TreeView's [drop](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/treeview/javascript/api/events/drop) event and then update the dataSource (accessible through in the event handler as `this.dataSource`).

The [DataSource](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/datasource) has its own API for data management, that can be used for reading/adding/removing/updating data.

And to preserve the state of the TreeView control, you can use its [methods](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/treeview/javascript/api/methods).

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I have tried with your information. But I couldn't use getDataSource() method in my dynamic data binding for tree view. I am trying to fetch data from a tree view sample is,  https://demos.shieldui.com/web/treeview/drag-and-drop .  Could you please help me in this.

Comment: In this above example link, I applied this.getDataSource([0]) to retrieve data it is success. But after drop any external data into the tree, this method doesn't fetch with the currently dropped data.  I hope i have explained clearly, expect your assistance. Thanks.